# How do I handle nulls in mySQL joins?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider table `t1` which has these three columns among others:

| nation | state | region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x1 |  |  |
| x1 | y1 |  |
| x1 | y1 | z1 |

and `t2`:

| nation | state | region | population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 |  |  | p1 |
| x1 | y1 |  | p2 |
| x1 | y1 | z1 | p3 |

How do I join `t1` and `t2` to get the population column in `t1`?

This only works when none of them are null:

```sql
join on t1.nation=t2.nation and t1.state=t2.state and t1.region=t2.region
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has a ["null-safe equals" operator <=>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) which is equivalent to standard SQL `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`, and which compares two NULLs as being equal.

So you may refactor your query to this:

```sql
SELECT t1.nation, t1.state, t1.region, t2.population
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t2.nation <=> t1.nation AND
       t2.state  <=> t1.state  AND
       t2.region <=> t1.region;
```